# R Error: Data and vector are not the same length

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot bacterial growth rates in R  using a premade script. Basically I am attempting to use a function to give me the steepest slope between a set of points. I'm using the following data frame "tmp":

```
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   54 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Strain     : Factor w/ 54 levels "11A023","11A045",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ 0          : num  0.048 0.05 0.047 0.053 0.051 0.051 0.041 0.05 0.049 0.045 ...
 $ 21.5       : num  0.04 0.042 0.037 0.037 0.041 0.03 0.031 0.043 0.037 0.036 ...
 $ 47.5       : num  0.027 0.041 0.032 0.035 0.034 0.026 0.02 0.042 0.034 0.03 ...
 $ 71.5       : num  0.026 0.039 0.028 0.032 0.032 0.022 0.019 0.041 0.03 0.031 ...
 $ 94.5       : num  0.025 0.037 0.027 0.026 0.03 0.017 0.015 0.037 0.028 0.024 ...
 $ 117.8333333: num  0.023 0.031 0.026 0.035 0.029 0.017 0.017 0.034 0.027 0.022 ...
 $ 144.5      : num  0.021 0.032 0.031 0.029 0.035 0.022 0.012 0.034 0.03 0.023 ...
 $ 154.75     : num  0.022 0.032 0.031 0.033 0.042 0.026 0.016 0.041 0.036 0.025 ...
 $ 194        : num  0.02 0.034 0.034 0.03 0.04 0.022 0.014 0.038 0.034 0.028 ...
```

And the following code:

```
tmp = read.csv("sorted_data.csv") #substitute your file name for 'sorted_data'
source("find_gr.R") #this command loads the script (find_gr) that contains the analysis functions (needs to be in the present working directory)
time <- seq(0,9.25) #edit as appropriate
                                #note that the growth rate output will be scaled by the time units you use here (per hour, per min, per century, etc.)

M = nrow(tmp)
N = ncol(tmp)

pdf("growth_rate_plots.pdf", paper="letter", width=7.5, height=10) #substitute your desired file name for 'growth_rate_plots'
growth.rates = NULL

for (i in 1:M) {
  print(i)
  gr <- findgr(tmp[i, 3:N], time, tmp[i, 2], int=12, r2=0.6) #3 in [i, 3:N] is the column number where the data starts;  
  #2 in [i, 2] is the column containg the label you want on the plot; 
  #int is number of points taken at one time as an interval to find the highest slope; 
  #vary (i.e. lower) r2, i.e. rsquared as needed, blanks can be a problem here
  growth.rates <- rbind(growth.rates, gr)
}
dev.off()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Error: Your data and time are not the same length.
Error in findgr(tmp[i, 3:N], time, tmp[i, 2], int = 12, r2 = 0.6) :
```

I believe this refers to the vector 'time' created. My dataframe is length 9 or 10 (not sure if I count $Strain in length). I have tried creating a time vector with varying lengths, but always get this error returned.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? What should I be looking for?

Much thanks for any help, I am a complete beginner at this.

**Scripts were obtained from https://www.princeton.edu/genomics/botstein/protocols/

Comment: Can you add the arguments for the loaded function `findgr` from the source `find_gr.R`?

Comment: This code is a bit of a mess, and fixing it is beyond the scope of an [mcve] which is more appropriate for this site. I would suggest taking the time to go through it line by line and trying to figure out what the inputs are and what each line does. Probably not what you wanted to hear but best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the script find_gr.R . First lines says:

```
findgr = function(x, t, plottitle, int=15, r2.cutoff=0.6) {
...
#are x and t the same length?
if (length(x) != length(t)) {
  cat("Error: Your data and time are not the same length.\n")
  stop()
}
```

Length of x and t has to be the same. Have a look what are you putting there. You are putting:

```
gr <- findgr(tmp[i, 3:N], time, ....
```

Time should be:

```
time <- seq(0, length(tmp[i, 3:N])-1)
```

-1 because sequence starts from 0.

However in my case (I generated some data) it produces some other errors. I hope this gives you a starting point.